# Convergence of the following sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am given with a non negative montotonically decreasing sequence of reals satisfying the following relation  $$a_{k+1} \leq a_k - ca_k^{\frac{2}{1+\varepsilon}}$$ where $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ and $c > 0$. I Know that this series is goint to converge to some number $a \geq 0$. But how to show that $a = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that that the limit has to be nonnegative since all the $a_k$ are. Now observe that $a_k^{\frac{2}{1+\varepsilon}} \geq a_k$, since $a_k\geq 0$ and $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, and therefore we get
$$a_{k+1} \leq a_k - ca_k^{\frac{2}{1 + \varepsilon}} \leq a_k - ca_k$$
(I'm doing this to avoid noninteger-powers of negative numbers, that's a delicate topic). Further,
$$ a = \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{k+1} = \lim_{k \to \infty} a_k $$
and hence, taking the limit in the inequality,
$$ a \leq a - ca.$$
This implies
$$ c a \leq 0.$$
Since $c > 0$,
$$ a \leq 0.$$
Combining $a \geq 0$ and $a \leq 0$ gives $a = 0$.

Comment: How can you say that  $a_k^{\frac{2}{1+\varepsilon}} \geq a_k$, since $a_k\geq 0$ and $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ . what if $0 < a_k < 1$?