# Convergence of a sequence if we know the recurrence relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, cauchy-sequences

Suppose we are given with a sequence of nonnegative terms denoted by $\{a_n\}$ and a recurrence relation satisfied by the sequence $$a_{k+1}-a_k \leq  F_k a_k^{\frac{2}{1+\epsilon}}  $$ where $ \epsilon > 0$,  $   F > 0$.

Suppose I don't know whether the limit of above sequence exists or not, and I want to find out the limit. So for that, I suppose that limit of this sequence is $a$ and from the recurrence relation, I get the value of $a=0$. So, Is it necessary to show that limit exists before calculating it or the value of limit itself implies its existence?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's necessary to show that the limit exists. Consider $a_{k+1} = -a_k, a_0 = 1.$ Trivially $\lim a_k$ doesn't exist, but plugging one in anyway gives you an (incorrect) answer. 2. How did you get $a = 0$ by plugging it into both sides of the inequality? The best I can do is say that $(\lim F_k) (\lim a_k)^{2/(1+\epsilon)} \ge 0,$ (which, btw, requires that the limit of $F_k$ exists, which too is unknown at this level of generality).

Comment: But given series is of positive terms? Does this matter?

Comment: Umm, suppose $F_k \ge 1$. Then the sequence $a_k = k$ satisfies the inequality for all $\epsilon >0,$ but clearly doesn't converge. (There'll be loads of such examples)

Comment: What if limit is coming as some value?

Comment: ^I don't know what that means. The limit of what? I think the situation is far too general to be able to say anything about the convergence of the $a_k,$ and even about the value the limit of the $a_k$ can take if it were known to exist (for instance, $a_k = 1 \,\forall k$ and $a_k = 2 \,\forall k$ will both satisfy the inequality - cf. point 2 in the first comment).

Comment: I mean in the first comment u have taken a sequence of both positive and negative terms, but in my question series is of nonnegative terms. So What if limit is coming as some value? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275934/convergence-of-the-following-sequence

Comment: So what if we don't know about the monotonicity of the sequence?

Comment: Yeah, but in the linked Q you had an $F_k$ less than $0$, which implies monotonicity and then the lower boundness does the trick. In what you have, we really cannot conclude anything - case in point that any constant non-negative sequence fits all conditions you have. The example in my first comment was only to highlight that it is *always* necessary to prove that a limit exists (and really, just, say, 2 + that example is a sequence that is non-convergent and satisfies your conditions for $F_k \ge 2$.) Again, the Q. is too general to have a significantly better answer.